# If $AB=BA$ and $\|A^p\|^{1/p}\|B^q\|^{1/q}<1$, then $(I-AB)^{-1}$ is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space, $A,B\in L(X)$ are bounded linear operators. Assume that $AB=BA$ and there exists integers $p,q\in\mathbb{N}_+$ such that $\|A^p\|^{1/p}\|B^q\|^{1/q}<1$. Prove that $(I-AB)^{-1}$ is bounded.

I've tried to use the Neuman formula, but I don't know how to contract the series.

Any hints will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: Do you mean $B^q$ instead of $B$? Can you please also refer me to the version of the Holder's inequality you are using (when $1/p + 1/q=1$)? I'm not familiar with it and can't find it.

Comment: @Dmitry Oh sorry, I've made a mistake!

Comment: Hint: bound $\|(AB)^{pq}\|$

Comment: I got it! Thanks!